# Query with where clause checking a variable with multiple values

Tags: mysql, heidisql

**Scenario:** I am trying to create a query where I want to retrieve multiple values from a table. Doing so by listing the values directly is straightforward, like so:

```
select * from product.text_data
where text_data.field_label = "Owner" or text_data.field_label = "Admin" or text_data.field_label = "Rule";
```

**Question:** Is it possible to do the same query, but instead feeding the list of fields into a variable, and checking the variable directly?

**Ex:**

```
set @idlist1 = ("Owner", "Admin", "Rule");
select * from product.text_data
where product.text_data.field_ref in @idlist1;
```

**Issue:** If I try to run this, I get the

```
SQL Error (1241): Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to define a list as a variable. You would have to declare your variable as a temporary table.

In your use case, you seem to be looking for dynamic sql.

```
declare @myList varchar(100)
set @myList = '( "Owner", "Admin", "Rule" )'
exec('SELECT * FROM product.text_data WHERE product.text_data.field_ref IN' + @myList)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing ' ' for the two brackets ()

variable should be set like this-

```
set @idlist1 = '("Owner","Admin","Rule")'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just tried that, but got error 1064 at the "where" line.

Comment: I forget to mention ; at end of variable maybe you should check